# Python and Java usage in 2004

Tags: java, python, usage-statistics

Does anyone know what happened in 2004 regarding the use of programming languages? I'm looking at [TIOBE](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html) statistic and some languages experienced a decrease of usage like Java and other like C++, Python or Visual Basic suffered a large increase. My question is: Why? Specifically in Python and Java.

Thanks.

Comment: Tiobe shows interest in a language. In 2004, Java 1.4 was very stable and most people were waiting for Java 5.0 If you search for `java 2003` `java 2004` `java 2005` You can see there is a dip in the number of results in 2004. Compare with `java 2011` and you may see why its at the top at the moment.

Comment: I found this (closed) thread after having the same question about TIOBE stats - from their own FAQ, it seems the dip is a result of Google making a significant change to their ranking algorithms in 2004: http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html